# Usar parent com input -- jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou tentando recuperar a id de uma div pai de uma input

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <input type="text" onfocus="mostra(this)">
</div>
```

Usando a função onFocus, ele me retorna *undefined*

```
function mostra()
{
    alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));  // output: undefined
}
```

Contudo, a titulo de curiosidade, dessa forma funciona e me retorna o dado certo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($("input").parent().attr("id"));  // output: parentDiv
});
```

O que estou fazendo de errado no uso do parent() usando *onfocus*?

Comment: O problema aí é que o **`this`** ali em `alert($(this).parent(...` não está se referindo ao this passado como parâmetro da função **mostra()** no Html, mas, sim ao this do contexto onde ele está inserido, por isso retorna **undefined**,  deveria pegar o parâmetro this passado na função e aí sim fazer a lógica necessária: `function mostra(this_referenciado) { alert($(this_referenciado).parent().attr("id")); })`

Comment: @LeAndrade desculpe me.. não entendi muito bem a sua colocação. 
Seria possível, por gentileza, mostrar em código em como seria a solução?

Comment: Não cumprimente, não agradeça e não faça deferências nas publicações. Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <input type="text" onfocus="mostra(this)">
</div>
```

No HTML acima, você está invocando a função `mostra` passando uma referência do próprio elemento como parâmetro.

Sendo assim, na função `mostra` você precisa capturar esse parâmetro por meio da declaração dos argumentos da função:

```
function mostra(elem)
{
    alert($(elem).parent().attr("id"));
}
```

Passar o `this` como argumento não muda o contexto de `this` na função, `this` é contextual, e tem valores diferentes em contextos diferentes.

Comment: Justamente isso que eu precisava!
Muito obrigado pelo tempo e disponibilidade.